# Next.js does not display meta tags in Next.js 14 using NextSeo

Tags: next.js

I have a strange problem with next-seo and next.js 14. In next.js 13, next-seo works without any issues. However, in next.js 14, only the metadata is working. The example code shows that the metadata is functioning, but the next-seo is not (the page is without a title).

```
...

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App111",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
...
```

```
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";
import Head from "next/head";
...


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <NextSeo
          title="Simple Usage Example"
          description="A short description goes here."
        />
      </Head>
```

NextSeo is not working on Next.js 14. How can I fix it?